# mediaelement.js responsive media query to serve mobile and desktop optimized videos

Tags: video, html5-video, media-queries, mediaelement.js

I want to serve two files. A low res for mobile and high res for desktops and tablets.

I've seen it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166958) and [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-audio-and-video-what-you-must-know/) (see: Sending Differently-Compressed Videos to Handheld Devices) to use a media query. I've found this works with a plain `<video>` tag but not with mediaelement.js

```
<video width="960" height="540" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="mobile.mp4" media="all and (max-width:600px)">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="desktop.mp4">
</video>
<script>jQuery('video').mediaelementplayer();</script>
```

(note: code simplified for clarity)

How can I get mediaelement.js to listen to the media query or is there another method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in function setSrc() in https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/src/js/me-mediaelements.js

mediaelement.js replace video's source tag with src attribute, but doesn't take care of the media query option.